# How many numbers between 1000 and 2500 are neither divisible by 4 nor 7?

Tags: combinatorics

Numbers divisible by 4:

((2500-1000)/4) + 1 = 376

Numbers divisible by 7:

((2499-1001)/7) + 1 = 215

Numbers divisible by both 4 and 7

((2492-1008)/28) + 1 = 54

Now, should I do

1500 - 376 - 215 + 54

or

1501 - 376 - 215 + 54

Comment: Subtract the amount divisible by 4, subtract the amount divisible by 7, then add the amount divisible by both

Comment: How many numbers are between 1000 and 2500?

Comment: Well, between 5 and 10 there are 6 numbers {5,6,7,8,9,10} but 10 - 5 = 5... that's where I'm struggling.

Comment: Just remember:  there are $n$ numbers from $1$ to $n$; $n=(n-1)+1$

Comment: Is "between" inclusive or exclusive of endpoints?

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Independent of the meaning of "between" you should be consistent. As you include both endpoints counting the numbers divisible by 4, you should include both of them counting the numbers divisible by 1 as well. Thus you should use 1501.